# User defined type guards: do I need to check member types?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm new to TypeScript, and trying to understand interfaces and type guards. Say I have an interface describing JSON passed between client and server:

```
interface Player {
  name: string
  score: number
}
```

My first attempt to write a type guard for this was:

```
function isPlayer (value: any): value is Player {
  const { name, score } = (value as Player)
  return typeof name == 'string' && typeof score == 'number'
}
```

My IDE warns me that the typeof checks are redundant: `'name' always has type 'string'`, etc. Instead, following examples in the TypeScript Handbook and elsewhere, all I need is to check that no members are undefined:

```
function isPlayer (value: any): value is Player {
  const { name, score } = (value as Player)
  return name !== undefined && score !== undefined
}
```

**Is this really enough?** My first thought was something about the type assertion `value as Player` that guarantees the types of its members. But the handbook itself [suggests not](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

> Type assertions are a way to tell the compiler “trust me, I know what I’m doing.” A type assertion is like a type cast in other languages, but performs no special checking or restructuring of data. It has no runtime impact, and is used purely by the compiler. TypeScript assumes that you, the programmer, have performed any special checks that you need.

[A quick experiment](https://tio.run/##bY5bCoMwEEX/s4rbH2NAugDBj@6gW0jjWAI6kSQWRFy7jY@@oJ9z597DiWNPwXjbx2WxHMk32hCurR7JYxIA645KhOgt34t0B@N8CnjobuQLMQvRDGyidQwbjl3@KKF5VCUeKfymGcchYtqoxc7CjCotoF9FlXqe4uB5q@FUVRi4psYy1ciyY/YTrx47u0@0j7e81LqTX96Sda3l5m0b5C/lvFfqLehaOrfunksbpBIzqA307wl2cS0syxM) seems to support this. The relaxed form of my `isPlayer` type guard will let through an object whose `score` is a string. Since this is the case, I'm confused why the handbook and every tutorial on type guards I've seen only mentions the simple form of an undefined check.

Say I had the following:

```
enum Stage {
  WaitingForCard = 'Waiting for card',
  PlacingBets = 'Placing bets',
  Scoring = 'Scoring',
}

interface Turn {
  stage: Stage
  players: string[]
}
```

It seems like a truly safe type guard would have to be something like:

```
function isRound (v: any): v is Round {
  const { stage, players } = (v as Round)

  if (stage != Stage.WaitingForCard || stage != Stage.PlacingBets || stage != Stage.Scoring) {
    return false
  }

  return players.every(player => typeof player == 'string')
}
```

Which doesn't even seem to be possible because the compiler complains about the exhaustive if condition. Is there anything to save me from such pain? **Do I just have to accept a certain amount of type unsafety around interfaces and type guards?**

Comment: assertions provide no guarantees about type safety. The opposite. You're telling the compiler to shut up bc you know what you're doing with an assertion.  Your IDE is wrong in this specific context about it being redundant.  That said, you might be going a little ... overboard with your type guards? Typeguards are important for things you don't control, or in contexts where multiple types are possible, ie discriminating between a union of possible types. Writing a type guard for every API response is overkill IMO if you control the API.

Comment: I suppose you're right that as idiomatic TypeScript it's overkill. I'm coming from some recent dabbling in Elm with its strict type system, where you would decode any incoming JSON to guarantee its shape. I was hoping that with TS I could have a similar experience. Absolute type safety sometimes seems overkill... until you get bitten by errors.

Comment: I've worked on a lot of enterprise TS apps and not one has ever type checked every API response.  Part of developing a front end is maintaining the interfaces of your API responses as you update your API. a lot of shops use type generators to automate that part of it a bit. You need to be able to rely on your own code a bit. and all these type guards might not even prevent errors depending on how you're writing and using them. type safety in TS is an incremental improvement over JS, but it's still inherently a loosely typed language where you can do what you want with types.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript allows you to be a bit lazy about your type guards and does not force you to check all (or actually any) of the properties, you can be as precise or as imprecise as you want (if you use ‛unknown‛ it becomes a bit harder). And then there is an issue with code where the types change and type guards are forgotten, leading to runtime errors :(

I was facing a similar problem, needing to manually define my type guards so I made a [TypeScript transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked) that can do it for me automatically. For example in your case:

```
import { isA } from 'ts-type-checked'; 

if (isA<Player>(value)) {
  // you are sure value is a Player here
}
```

You can find the guide on how to use it in your project on the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-type-checked#installation).

Disclaimer: ofc I am an author of the library :)

Comment: That's a really cool library! The sort of feature I was hoping TS would have. I'll look into it. Also a good point about drift between types and type guards.